# Packing php, mysql and VB.net together

Tags: php, mysql, .net, vb.net

I've just finished designing a POS software using VB.net I've used mysql and php (to display a few important banners etc. And used inside VB.net using webbrowser fuction) . Is there a way that I can place all the php and mysql db inside the debug folder and avoid using xamp or any other localhost server tools? Basically I want to make the application free of any dependency of third party softwares. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: You can't use a MySQL database without MySQL being installed.  It's a database server and without the server, the database is useless.  If you don't want to use a database server then you need to use a file-based database, e.g. SQLite.  There's also the option of using SQL Server Express, which is not part of .NET but is still first-party software, given that it is from Microsoft.  I don't use PHP myself but I would assume that it needs an interpreter or the like installed too.

Comment: Why did you use PHP and MySQL for displaying those banners, - and not just do that using VB.net as well? It sounds like your using two technologies, where a better/cleaner/simpler way would be to use just one. Or if you can show an example of your code, where you display the banners...

Comment: Php was needed to display in proper style and CSS benefits. I'm designing it for a client and his design demand is impossible to meet without using CSS + bootstrap and php . The reason I'm asking this is it'll be very difficult for the client to install a server tool and then import the database and all to run the software I designed

Comment: Is this supposed to be SaaS?  You can't expect to run either PHP or MySQL in client-side code, but you could connect to a remote web application for the PHP/MySQL code.

Comment: It's kind of SaaS designed using VB.net. It's a Point of Sale system. I figured that's it's not possible to run php or mysql on client side, but I was thinking there might be something I can do apart from using cloud based services.

Comment: So the client doesn't have to go through all the hassles of installing and setting up a webserver on his end

Comment: How about loading the content in an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)? However... Regardless of what you do, - then content must be on a server somewhere.

Comment: Yeah server thing is the issue. The client isn't paying for the server (as he wants the software to be offline for his shop). Guess he has to take the hassles of installing the webserver and configurating it.